# For every normal operator, is there a unitary operator with the same spectral measure?

Tags: operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Given a (bounded) normal operator $N$ (satisfying $N^*N=NN^*$) in a von Neumann algebra $A$, does $A$ always contain a unitary operator $U$ having the same spectral (projection-valued) measure as $N$?

If $N$ has a purely discrete spectrum, then the answer is clearly yes, because then $N$ has the form $N = \sum_n z_n P_n$ where the $P_n$ are mutually orthogonal projection operators and the $z_n$ are distinct complex coefficients. Replacing the original coefficients with any list of distinct unit-magnitude coefficients gives a unitary operator $U$ with the desired property.

Is the answer *always* yes? If so, is there a simple proof (or a reference)? If not, then what is a counterexample?

I browsed other questions on math.stackexchange with similar keywords but didn't notice any that answered this particular question.

Comment: What if you take a 1-1 Borel function $f : \mathbb{C} \to S^1$ and let $U = f(N)$ using the functional calculus?

Comment: What do you mean by "having the same spectral measure"? The spectral measure of a unitary operator is supported in $S^1$ while the spectral measure of $N$ need not be so. It seems that your are using an equivalence of spectral measures that factors the equivalence of the underlying subsets of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez  I'm not a mathematician, and I'm probably not using the right words. I'm trying to ask if, given $N$, there is always a $U$ that implicitly defines the same set of mutually commuting projection operators via the spectral decomposition theorem. I understand that $N$ and $U$ will typically have different spectra (numbers $z$ for which $N-z$ or $U-z$ is not invertible), but can the projection-valued measure in the spectral decomposition theorem be defined independently of the spectrum?  Sorry if my vocabulary is mixed up. I know that makes deciphering my question difficult.

Comment: @NateEldredge Your comment opened my eyes to the fact that I might just need a better understanding of what a Borel function is, and also of exactly how the spectral decomposition theorem works. My background is in physics, and I tend to think in terms of smoothness or continuity. The idea of "...a 1-1 [useful type of] function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow S^1$ ..." is new to me.  After seeing your comment, I started searching for sources that could help me build better intuition with relatively little effort, but it seems that my "relatively little effort" criterion might be unrealistic!

Comment: @DanYand: Heuristically, a Borel function is anything you can describe explicitly without using the axiom of choice.  For example, to get a 1-1 Borel function from the unit square to the unit interval, you can do something like mapping $(0.123456\dots, 0.789789\dots)$ to $0.172839475869\dots$ by interleaving the digits.  One could use the same sort of trick to get a 1-1 Borel function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $S^1$.

Comment: @DanYand: More generally, between any two uncountable complete separable metric spaces, there is a bijective Borel function.  This fact is found in lots of measure theory and descriptive set theory books, e.g. Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for that guidance. I think you've pointed me in the right direction, and I'm looking forward to studying this. Thanks again!